# How to post customer firstname & lastname into database magento 2.1.1?

Tags: magento2, login

I added two fields for customers in my website. When customer will go for PIN to verify their account that I want to post customer **First-nam**e and **Last-name** through the form. Now, what can I do can, anyone please help. Please check my attached image below.
[image]

Comment: Can you put more details?

Comment: This is my form actually. Actually I just added First-name and Last-name text field to send the data to database. I want to just send first-name and last-name in customer table under first-name and last-name. Now OPT is working but other fields could send any data to database. Which code I have to put?